# Cocoa base64 decoding. And NSString initWithData:encoding: return nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, encoding, base64, mime-types

I have MIME header:

```
Subject: =?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCJzEnYidWJ1UnWSdRJ1wnURsoQg==?=
=?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCJ1kbKEIgGyRCLWIbKEIxNzUzNTk=?=
=?ISO-2022-JP?B?IBskQidjGyhCIBskQidjJ1EnWydkJ1EbKEI=?=
=?ISO-2022-JP?B?IBskQidXGyhCLRskQideJ2AnUidaJ10nbhsoQg==?=
```

When i try to decode first string `GyRCJzEnYidWJ1UnWSdRJ1wnURsoQg==` (base64 decode and then `NSSring initWithData: encoding:`), all right. My code works fine for hundreds of different MIME headers except follows...

...When i try to decode second sring `GyRCJ1kbKEIgGyRCLWIbKEIxNzUzNTk=`, `NSString initWithData:encoding:` return `nil`

For example, http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en decode all strings correctly (dont forget encode this strings from base64 befor using this site).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a base64 problem, it's an ISO-2022-JP problem. Actually it's a JIS-X-0208 problem. If you look at the base64-decoded (but still ISO-2022-JP encoded) string, you'll see that it contains the sequence `ESC $ B - b` (bytes 9 through 13). The first three are the ISO-2022-JP shift sequence to shift into JIS-X-0208-1983 (see [RFC 1468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1468) for details), and the next two are supposed to be a 2-byte encoding of a character, but if you [work it out](http://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/encodings.html#encodings-JIS-X-0208) it's on line 13 of the *kuten* grid, which isn't defined.

tl;dr: That's not a valid character.

Comment: And if the data is not valid in the encoding you tried to decode it from, then the decoder will return `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing a final `=` in your string?